# Access query only return 1 max date result per select MAX statement

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've been beating my head for a while on this one...

I'm working with a legacy Access database (which I'm working on phasing out/replacing), and an issue came up where duplicate records are now showing from the query where we used to never see duplicate records.

We pull expiration dates from several tables, and the query returns the most future expiration date for each person, for each certificate they have.

The whole query is quite large, but the problem area, that is left join duplicated for each table of expirations, is this:

```
SELECT Courses.[id], Person.FirstName, Person.MiddleName, Person.LastName, Courses.Code, Codes.Name, Courses.Date, Courses.[P/F/I/C], Courses.ExpirationDate, Courses.Grade
FROM Codes INNER JOIN (Courses INNER JOIN Person ON Courses.[id] = Person.[id]) ON Codes.Code = Courses.Code
WHERE (
    Courses.ExpirationDate = (SELECT MAX(ExpirationDate) FROM Courses b WHERE b.ExpirationDate >= Date() AND (b.[id] = Courses.[id]) AND b.Code = 'c0' AND ((b.[P/F/I/C])='P' Or (b.[P/F/I/C])='C'))
) OR (
    Courses.ExpirationDate = (SELECT MAX(ExpirationDate) FROM Courses b WHERE b.ExpirationDate >= Date() AND (b.[id] = Courses.[id]) AND b.Code = 'c1' AND ((b.[P/F/I/C])='P' Or (b.[P/F/I/C])='C'))
) OR (
    Courses.ExpirationDate = (SELECT MAX(ExpirationDate) FROM Courses b WHERE b.ExpirationDate >= Date() AND (b.[id] = Courses.[id]) AND b.Code = 'c2' AND ((b.[P/F/I/C])='P' Or (b.[P/F/I/C])='C'))
) OR (
    Courses.ExpirationDate = (SELECT MAX(ExpirationDate) FROM Courses b WHERE b.ExpirationDate >= Date() AND (b.[id] = Courses.[id]) AND b.Code = 'c3' AND ((b.[P/F/I/C])='P' Or (b.[P/F/I/C])='C'))
) OR (
    Courses.ExpirationDate = (SELECT MAX(ExpirationDate) FROM Courses b WHERE b.ExpirationDate >= Date() AND (b.[id] = Courses.[id]) AND b.Code = 'c4' AND ((b.[P/F/I/C])='P' Or (b.[P/F/I/C])='C'))
) OR (
    Courses.ExpirationDate = (SELECT MAX(ExpirationDate) FROM Courses b WHERE b.ExpirationDate >= Date() AND (b.[id] = Courses.[id]) AND b.Code = 'c5' AND ((b.[P/F/I/C])='P' Or (b.[P/F/I/C])='C'))
) OR (
    Courses.ExpirationDate = (SELECT MAX(ExpirationDate) FROM Courses b WHERE b.ExpirationDate >= Date() AND (b.[id] = Courses.[id]) AND b.Code = 'c6' AND ((b.[P/F/I/C])='P' Or (b.[P/F/I/C])='C'))
) OR (
    Courses.ExpirationDate = (SELECT MAX(ExpirationDate) FROM Courses b WHERE b.ExpirationDate >= Date() AND (b.[id] = Courses.[id]) AND b.Code = 'c7' AND ((b.[P/F/I/C])='P' Or (b.[P/F/I/C])='C'))
)
ORDER BY Courses.[id], Courses.Code
```

If one of those OR clauses has two future expiration dates for a single person in a single class (they re-certified before they expired), the query returns both records. It should only return the MAX of those two records. Any ideas as to what I'm missing in the above query? I can post the rest of the query that this one is nested in if it helps, but I'm pretty sure this is where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you really want this:

```
WHERE Courses.ExpirationDate = (SELECT MAX(b.ExpirationDate)
                                FROM Courses b
                                WHERE b.ExpirationDate >= Date() AND
                                      b.[id] = Courses.[id] AND
                                      b.Code IN ('c0', 'c1', . . .) AND
                                      b.Code = Courses.Code AND
                                      b.[P/F/I/C]) IN ('P', 'C')
                               )
```

This is a single condition with an additional correlation condition on `Code`.

Comment: Thanks! I actually ended up just being able to do one select MAX query like you are saying, but since it already had to be duplicated for every course in the parent query, I was able to remove all of the ORs and just do the select MAX query once for each course. So instead of having all the ORs the WHERE only included `Courses.ExpirationDate = (SELECT MAX(ExpirationDate) FROM Courses b WHERE b.ExpirationDate >= Date() AND (b.[id] = Courses.[id]) AND b.Code = 'c6' AND ((b.[P/F/I/C])='P' Or (b.[P/F/I/C])='C'))`

Comment: I will adopt your `AND b.[P/F/I/C]) IN ('P', 'C')` logic though, because that is much cleaner. Thanks!